# 2 columns layout: how to make the 2 columns scrolling independently

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, overflow

I bought a `Bootstrap Theme` a while ago and I need to customize it. I target only 1024px screen and above.

Here is the demo page: `http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB05FN804/`

Basically the theme is a `2-columns layout`. Wherever your cursor is on the page you scroll up and down the right/main column. Therefore if your cursor is on the left columns, scrolling up and down scrolls the whole page.

I'd like to provide a `2 scrolling mechanism`: a specific scroll for the left columns and a specific scroll for the main/right column.

I added `overflow: scroll` on `<nav id="primary">`. It is working; it you open all the folder menus in order to exceed the height, you can scroll up and down.

**However when you reach the top or the bottom, it continues to scroll the right column.**

This is what I want to fix.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your page is leveraging browser scroll feature. One robust way to prevent right column to stop scrolling when you are in left navigation is to set Overflow:Hidden; to  the body and remove overflow inline css when you mouse out from primary nav..

Simple jQuery should help you?

```
$("#primary").hover(
    function(){$("body").css("overflow", "hidden")}, 
    function(){$("body").css("overflow", "")}
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, I didn't think of it :p